# Wild cards for a folder in batch script

Tags: batch-file

Am trying to execute an EXE (Setup.EXE) file that is in the folder called "ABC 8.8.0 build and package 12" but after running the above batch script, I get an error saying "Windows cannot find this path...". The folder name can vary but however the first 10 chars of the folder name will remain constant. Can someone help please.

```
Start ""  "%cd%\ABC 8.8.0 Build.*\SetUp.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%cd%\abc 8.8.0 *"') do start "" "%%a\setup.exe"
```

Perform a directory scan, in basic form of directories only that match the filemask "abc 8.8.0 +*something*" and assign the entirety of the resultant string to `%%a` (this is the meaning of `delims=` - no delimiters). Execute the `setup.exe` command from *each* matching directoryname found.

Comment: Thank you Magoo for the response. When I executed the above comment it throwed me an error but I could figure out what the problem.  The modification is - there should be "\" inplace of "." in this string. "%%a.setup.exe". After this change is worked fine for me.  HOw can I make the command wait till the EXE completes its work.

Comment: ...to change the `.` between the `%%a` and the `setup` to a backslash. Fixed!